# Linq distinct & max

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to query this table:

```
symbol    time
------    ----------
aaa       2013-04-18 09:10:28.000    
bbb       2013-04-18 09:10:27.000    
aaa       2013-04-18 09:10:27.000    
bbb       2013-04-18 09:10:26.000
```

I need **one row** for all distinct **symbols having the biggest time** value. How do I have to write my linq query?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Group rows by *symbol* and then select from each group item with max *time* (*Table* is your database table name from context):

```
from r in Table
group r by r.symbol into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.time).First()
```

Same with method syntax:

```
Table.GroupBy(r => r.symbol)
     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.time).First());
```

Comment: If you use `GroupBy` it is assured that there is at least one row, so you can use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter agree, but I was not sure if it EF (which often complaining on `First()`), so I decided to leave `FirstOrDefault()` here :) But, OK thus it Linq to SQL, I'll update

Comment: even Linq-To-Entities should support `First`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx (`Last`/`LastOrDefault` are not supported)

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, possibly that's [old fear](http://www.ginktage.com/2010/11/first-throws-error-in-linq-or-entity-framework-queries/) which was fixed now. Good to know :)

Answer (score 9):

try out this

```
var q = MyTable.GroupBy(x => x.symbol )
               .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.time).First());
```

or use max like this

```
 var data = from r in MyTable
                   group r by r.symbol into g
                   select new { name= g.Key, data= g.Max(a=>a.time) };
```

Answer (score 3):

I would actually use.

```
void Main()
{
    var set = new [] {
        new Foo{A = "aaa", B = 1},
        new Foo{A = "bbb", B = 2},
        new Foo{A = "aaa", B = 3},
        new Foo{A = "bbb", B = 4},
    };

    var result = from x in set
                group x.B by x.A into g
                select new {id = g.Key, biggest = g.Max()};

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use lambda expression with Linq -

```
var result= (from li in List.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.time)
                       select li).FirstOrDefault();
```