# Keeping one row of nearly identical rows in a datatable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable where there can possibly be rows that are almost identical except for the values in one column "FileID".  The column that can differ contains Int32 data and I'd like to keep only the row that has the maximum value of this column when the rows are duplicated.  If rows aren't duplicate I'd like to keep the single row.

```
var Test = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new
                {
                    Tool = r.Field<string>("Tool"),
                    Plate = r.Field<string>("Plate"),
                    Lot = r.Field<string>("Lot"),
                    Time1 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time1"),
                    Tool2 = r.Field<string>("Tool2"),
                    Time2 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time2"),
                    Recipe = r.Field<string>("Recipe"),
                    Row = r.Field<Int16>("Row")
                }).OrderBy(t => t.Max(r => r.Field<Int32>("FileID")));
```

This seems to be filtering down the rows correctly but I lose the FileID column.  I want to put the results from this query back into a datatable with the max FileID so that it can be used in my form's datagridview.  How is this possible?

Comment: Add a select clause?

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076805/linq-distinct-max) maybe what you looking for.

Comment: Add `FileID` to the select columns list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you group by the appropriate columns, you need to select just the row with the max `FileID` from each group, and then you can use the `CopyToDataTable` extension:

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new {
                Tool = r.Field<string>("Tool"),
                Plate = r.Field<string>("Plate"),
                Lot = r.Field<string>("Lot"),
                Time1 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time1"),
                Tool2 = r.Field<string>("Tool2"),
                Time2 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time2"),
                Recipe = r.Field<string>("Recipe"),
                Row = r.Field<Int16>("Row")
            })
            .Select(rg => rg.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<Int32>("FileID")).First())
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Note: Given that you are using LINQ to Objects, `OrderBy`/`First` is not the most efficient way to find the row with max `FileID`. You may not have enough data to matter, but you can use an extension method, `MaxBy` that takes one pass through the data and finds the appropriate row:

```
public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) > 0 ? a : b);

var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new {
                Tool = r.Field<string>("Tool"),
                Plate = r.Field<string>("Plate"),
                Lot = r.Field<string>("Lot"),
                Time1 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time1"),
                Tool2 = r.Field<string>("Tool2"),
                Time2 = r.Field<DateTime>("Time2"),
                Recipe = r.Field<string>("Recipe"),
                Row = r.Field<Int16>("Row")
            })
            .Select(rg => rg.MaxBy(r => r.Field<Int32>("FileID")))
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked great.  I was working on it a different way without the `CopyToDataTable` and while it was working it was adding a lot of extra code. This is much cleaner.

Comment: Just saw the update as well.  There will only be up to a handful of duplicate rows for each group so I don't think it should change much but I'll try the MaxBy to see how it compares.