# Take unique records from text file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, timestamp, unique, icollection

I have set up `ICollection<User>` list:

```
public ICollection<User> MyUsers { get; set; }
public IList<User> GetUserList(string path)
{
        MyUsers = File.ReadAllLines(path)
           .Where(linia => linia.Length > 1)
           .Select(line => Parse(line))
           .ToList();            

        return new List<User>(MyUsers);
}

private static User Parse(string line)
{
        var column = line.Split('|');

        return new User
        {
            ReadTime = column [0],
            idUser = column [1],
            LastName = column [2],
            FirstName = column [3],
            City = column[4]
        };
}
```

My source text file looks as below:

```
2019-03-03|1|LN1|FN1|Berlin
2019-03-03|2|LN2|FN2|Rome
2019-03-03|3|LN3|FN3|Wien
2019-03-03|4|LN4|FN4|Londyn
....
2019-03-27|1|LN1|FN1|Berlin
2019-03-27|2|LN2|FN2|Rome
2019-03-27|3|LN3|FN3|Wien
2019-03-27|4|LN4|FN4|Londyn
```

When I run this, I'm getting list with the same records, only `ReadTime` is diffrent.

How can I set up **unique** `MyUsers` list, where column `ReadTime` will be taken last date?

Comment: look at  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076805/linq-distinct-max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with simple `GroupBy` method:

```
  MyUsers = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Where(linia => linia.Length > 1)
    .Select(line => Parse(line))
    .GroupBy(
      u => u.idUser, 
      (key, grp) => new User() {
        ReadTime = grp.Select(u => u.ReadTime).Max(),
        idUser = key,
        LastName = grp.Select(u => u.LastName).FirstOrDefault(),
        FirstName = grp.Select(u => u.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),
        City = grp.Select(u => u.City).FirstOrDefault(),
      })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @4est Just place the code after using `Parse` mathod

Comment: you have twice `ToList()`, please remove first.....but I have tested and working great, thanks!

Comment: @4est Then you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: I will accept, sure, but please remove first `ToList()`, thanks

Comment: Thank you for quick turnaround :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)-NuGet-package, there is useful [DistinctBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#distinctby)-function:

```
MyUsers = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Where(linia => linia.Length > 1)
    .Select(line => Parse(line))
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.ReadTime)
    .DistinctBy(r => new { r.City, r.FirstName, r.idUser, r.LastName })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: MoreLinq - this is NuGet pack?

Comment: Yes, you can find it from Nuget

Comment: need to test other answers first :)

Answer (score 1):

We can `GroupBy` and find `Max` date for each group:

```
   IEnumerable<string> result = File
     .ReadLines(path)    
     .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // to be on the safe side
     .Select(line => {
        int p = line.IndexOf('|');

        return new {
          date = line.Substring(0, p), // date to take Max
          key = line.Substring(p + 1)  // group key
        };
      })
     .GroupBy(item => item.key, item => item.date)
     .Select(chunk => string.Join("|", chunk.Key, chunk.Max(item => item)));
```

Having filtered out duplicates we can then parse into a collection:

```
   MyUsers = result
     .Select(line => Parse(line))
     .ToList();
```